# Flash object (Jquery Webcam) not show on Jquery Dialog in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-webcam-plugin

I use jquery webcam in a jquery dialog it works fine in Chrome but it does not show anything in IE.

```
    $("#camera-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 380,
        resizable: false,
        height: 320,
        open: function(event, ui){
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Popup")");
        },
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fadeOut",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });
```

and this is my partial view Popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#camera").webcam({
             width: 320,
             height: 240,
             mode: "save",
             swffile: "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jscam.swf")",
             onTick: function () { },
             onSave: function () { },
             onCapture: function () {
                 webcam.save("@Url.Content("~/Cap")/");
             },
             debug: function () { },
             onLoad: function () { }
        });

</script>
    <div id="camera">
    </div>
```

and if I do not use the dialog but just put it on a page then it works fine too.

What's happening and how can I make this work in IE too?

Thank you in advance.